# Weird comments above PHP function declarations

Tags: php, comments

I noticed that a lot of scripts have these type of comments:

```
/**
 * Retrieve list of themes with theme data in theme directory.
 *
 * The theme is broken, if it doesn't have a parent theme and is missing either
 * style.css and, or index.php. If the theme has a parent theme then it is
 * broken, if it is missing style.css; index.php is optional. The broken theme
 * list is saved in the {@link $wp_broken_themes} global, which is displayed on
 * the theme list in the administration panels.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 * @global array $wp_broken_themes Stores the broken themes.
 * @global array $wp_themes Stores the working themes.
 *
 * @return array Theme list with theme data.
 */
function get_themes() {
    global $wp_themes, $wp_broken_themes;

    ...

    return $wp_themes;
}
```

It looks like some kind of documentation for the function, but what's up with the words prepended with `@` ?

Like @since, @global, @return, @access, @param etc...?

I know what they mean, but why do they have @ in front of them? Do they need to identify with some kind of documentation app.?

Comment: Wow I've never really looked at WP source code before, `global $wp_broken_themes` sounds like some potentially awful code is going on!

Comment: They're not "weird". @Wesley: WP code is horrendous; well, it's PHP so go figure.

Comment: @Tomalak regarding PHP hate: It's not the car, it's the driver :)

Comment: @Wesley: You see crappy drivers more often in a Ford Mondeo than you do in a military jeep: fact. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Either one will crash in the hands of a fool, but point taken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the JavaDoc Standard. Most likely the author picked it because most IDEs automatically format it nicely.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Comment: hey thanks! do you know a free IDE that does this? I'm using "we builder 2010" and they appear as comments

Comment: NetBeans is a fabulous free IDE that supports Java(ofc.), C/++, Python, PHP and lots more via modules!

Comment: I second NetBeans, just tried it last week and was impressed. I'm a Notepad++ junkie trying to quit the habit and move to something more powerful.

Comment: No, it is not Javadoc, it is phpDocumentator. Similar, but not the same. NetBeans handles that style of documentation pretty well.

Comment: I said it's the JavaDoc Standard. Everything that looks similar is some kind of derivate and so is phpDoc.

Comment: I did not say it is not derivative ([adaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc)) of Javadoc, I just said it is not Javadoc. Php Documentator is something that aims at introducing Javadoc-like comments into PHP. But it is not the same - it is derivative, newer, limited and focusing on different language.

Answer (score 3):

> Do they need to identify with some kind of documentation app.?

They are useful with auto-documentors like [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/), and in general are a good way to document your code. As [wasabi has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924528/weird-comments-above-php-function-declarations/5924540#5924540), IDE's can pick up on them as well and do some helpful stuff for you, like function argument type suggestions.

Even if you aren't documenting your code, it's a good habit to be in - just don't feel the need to get carried away with it at some folks tend to do (documenting every possible thing).

Answer (score 3):

It's [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc), which is an adaption of the beloved Javadoc format.

These documentation formats are both somewhat more readable thanks to their enforced consistency, and useful for IDEs and automatic documentation generators such as [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) which is, more or less, [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) for PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely [PHP Documentator](http://www.phpdoc.org/). The "@something" parts are used to add information to the documentation. Please see [PHP Documentator's documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.pkg.html) for details - it even has tool for generating documentation files from comments ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpdocu/files/PhpDoc/)) in PHP Documentator's format.

Hope that helps you.